# SQL Social - Online Users

Tags: mysql, social-networking

I've got a table

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_username` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `user_password` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `user_email` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `user_enabled` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1',
  `user_verified` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  `user_verified_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `user_signup_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `user_login_date` datetime default NULL,
  `user_status` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `user_online` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`)
)
```

Every time a user visits the website **user_login_date** updates and **user_online** is set to *1*, which means he's online.

What query can I send to switch **user_online** to *0* (offline) if user's last visit was 10 minutes ago?

I've already done like that

```
UPDATE tbl_users SET user_online = '0' WHERE (NOW() - user_login_date) > INTERVAL 10 minute
```

But that didn't help.

Comment: This doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Does that mean if I am still active, but logged in 11 minutes ago, then I am not online?

Comment: No. I mean every time a page is loaded, login date updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the calculations on the constants so that an index on `user_login_date` can be used:

```
UPDATE tbl_users
SET user_online = '0'
WHERE NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE > user_login_date
```